# jsonに1次元配列をセットする場合の記述について

Tags: python, json, api, array

現在、Pythonの勉強をしており、APIを利用したプログラムを作成しています。
が、JSONにセットする値に1次元配列を利用したいのですが、うまくいきません。
どのように記述すればよろしいでしょうか。

わかりづらい点もあるかと思いますが、ご教授いただけないでしょうか…

これを↓

```
json_data = {
    'destination': {
        'XXX': XX,
    },
    'source': {
        'ipRanges': [
            "11111",    // ★ここを配列にしたい
            "22222"     // ★ここを配列にしたい
          ]
    }
}
```

イメージとしてはこうしたい↓です。（エラーとなってしまいますが、、、）

```
json_data = {
    'destination': {
        'XXX': XX,
    },
    'source': {
        'ipRanges': [
            test["values"] //★配列について記述はしていないですが、定義してあるものと考えていただければ幸いです。
          ]
    }
}
```

Comment: 前の質問と類似の内容ですが、それは[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/26370)ではないですか？ 既存のサービスを利用したくて問題が発生しているなら、何のサービスをどのように利用したいか等の前提となる情報を追記してみてください。自分で新規に独自のサービスや機能を構築・追加しようとして問題が発生しているなら、同様に前提となる情報や、自分でやりたい事や参考にしている書籍や記事などについて追記してみてください。

Comment: 貴重なご指摘、ありがとうございます。以後注意致します。

Answer (score 0):

このようなイメージであっているのでしょうか？

```py
import json
r_array = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [3, 5, 7, 8, 9],
]

json_data = {
    'destination': {
        'XXX': "XX",
    },
    'source': {
        'ipRanges': r_array
    }
}

print(json_data)

json_str = json.dumps(json_data, indent=2)

print(json_str)
```

出力結果：

```
{'destination': {'XXX': 'XX'}, 'source': {'ipRanges': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 5, 7, 8, 9]]}}
{
  "destination": {
    "XXX": "XX"   
  },
  "source": {
    "ipRanges": [
      [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5
      ],
      [
        3,
        5,
        7,
        8,
        9
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

<追記：Numpy使用時>

```
from array import array


import json
import numpy as np

ra_array = np.array(
    [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]
    ]
)


json_data = {
    'destination': {
        'XXX': "XX",
    },
    'source': {
        'ipRanges': ra_array.tolist()
    }
}

print(json_data)

json_str = json.dumps(json_data, indent=2)

print(json_str)
```

配列を扱いたい場合、Numpyを使用したほうが便利かと思いますので、一応追記しました。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます！
記載いただいた通りかと思います！
ググればよいものかと思うのですが、「indent=2」については何をしているものなのかうかがってもよろしいでしょうか、、、、

Comment: jsonはよく使用すると思いますので、Pythonドキュメントで調べておくとよいと思います。dumpsメソッドで文字列に変換していますが、見やすく改行、インデントがあったほうがよいので、indentにより空白2つ分インデント表示させるものです。人が見るために便利というだけです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。助かりました…